# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH' in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was able to find a lot of articles regarding this issue, but nothing helped. So I'm trying to insert data to the table:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TV.EIP_Year_Month] ([Number], [Data])
;WITH months(MonthNumber) AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MonthNumber + 1 
    FROM months
    WHERE MonthNumber < 12
)
SELECT
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + 
        CAST(MonthNumber AS VARCHAR) + '-01'  AS Data
FROM 
    months
```

I get this error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: `WITH` *always* comes at the beginning of queries, never in the middle. This is true even if you're using the results of the `WITH` as a subquery somewhere. Keep that in mind and you'll be fine.

Comment: Additionally: the `;` needs to be at the **end** of a statement (or before it which is implicitly at the end of the previous statement), **not** in the middle of it.

Comment: The semicolon is a statement terminator, not a statement beginninator. Remove the statement terminator in the middle of your statement and it will work.

Comment: I would use a tally table here instead of a recursive cte. When you use a recursive cte for counting like that it is really doing a loop behind the scenes which can be challenging for performance. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/ Obviously for 12 rows it isn't going to be a big deal but something you should be aware of. Using a tally table here would much simpler. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: @JeroenMostert not "always".   WITH can be in the middle of the statement when it's used to introduce a query hint.   : )

Comment: @SeanLange I want to petition for a statement beginninator now

Comment: This is why I hate people being taunt the syntax `;WITH`. it's so wrong... Just like others said, it's called a terminator, not a "Begginnator". You don't start your C# statements with a Semicolon (in fact, doing so would generate a syntax error), so why are you T-SQL? /headdesk

Comment: @TabAlleman: Also, it will come somewhere in the middle when used as a table or column name -- albeit in brackets. All important stuff to keep in mind. :-P But yes, it should have been "common table expressions, that start with the keyword `WITH`, ..."

Comment: Isn't every statement's terminator a new statement's beginninator?

Comment: @TabAlleman no. For `SELECT 1;` there is not "new" statement. Likewise `;SELECT 1` is only a "beginninator. If Microsoft ever implement their veiled threat of a deprecation, I'd guess the latter will fail. As would something like `SELECT 1 SELECT 'a' ;WITH C AS (SELECT 2 AS I) SELECT I FROM C`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would put the WITH statement before the INSERT like so:

```
WITH months(MonthNumber) AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MonthNumber+1 
    FROM months
    WHERE MonthNumber < 12
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TV.EIP_Year_Month]
  ([Number]
  ,[Data])
SELECT cast(datepart(year, GETDATE()) as varchar) + '-' + CAST(MonthNumber AS VARCHAR) + '-01'  as Data
FROM months
```

Assuming the rest of your statement works for you, arranging it as such should work.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Much easier than I expected (and spend time on searching how to make it work).

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH months(MonthNumber) AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MonthNumber+1 
    FROM months
    WHERE MonthNumber < 12
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TV.EIP_Year_Month]
      ([Number]
      ,[Data])
select ?[Number]?, cast(datepart(year, GETDATE()) as varchar) + '-' + CAST(MonthNumber AS VARCHAR) + '-01'  as Data
FROM months
```

Comment: A code-only reply is a poor answer. It is made worse by your inclusion of "?[Number]?" without explanation and by the continued use of a cast to varchar with no length.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to use `CTE` for just 12 months :

```
select datefromparts(year(getdate()), MonthNumber, 1) as [date]
from ( values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
     ) t (MonthNumber);
```

You can use [DATEFROMPARTS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to convert date.

Comment: Thanks, @Yogesh that's a very good idea as well. I'm new at SQL and that was the only solution I was able find and think of.